# Getting "Could not read config file" error during product save

Tags: magento2, migration, data-migration

I've Migrated Magento1 to Magento2.2.5, when I updated a product either changing any field or not **then getting "Could not read config file" error:-**

Please visit on below screenshot for the same :-

http://nimb.ws/sar6ce

Waiting for your response.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a permissions issue to me, possibly with a module xml file. If you've recently upgraded, have you set permissions for the new files?

Magento reccomend the following for a multiple user site (ie, you're editing files with one user, and the hosting software such as Apache/Nginx is running as another user):

```
cd <your Magento install dir>
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
sudo chown -R :<web server group> .
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

The web server group on Ubuntu or Debian is typically www-data.

If it's a custom module you can change permissions for every file and directorry in app/code, or set the specific module path to affect only that module:

```
find app/code -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find app/code -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
```

Reccomended reading for more info on Magento 2 permissions: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried but doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd <your Magento install dir> 

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644 permission for files

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755 permission for directory 

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777 permission for var folder    

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```